# How to correctly set up event listener?

Tags: typo3, typo3-11.x

Using Typo3 version 11.5.24

I'm trying to listen to the `TYPO3\CMS\Core\Cache\Event\CacheFlushEvent` inside an extension.

The documentation says, I just have to configure the listener in the file `Configuration/Services.yaml`.

My config looks like this (I did not provide the method name, so __invoke should be called automatically):

```
  Vendor\MyExt\EventLister\CacheFlushEventListener:
    arguments:
      $logger: 'Psr\Log\LoggerInterface'
    tags:
      - name: event.listener
        identifier: 'vendor-my-ext-flush-listener'
        event: TYPO3\CMS\Core\Cache\Event\CacheFlushEvent
```

I can also see in the `Configuration` tab in the backend, that the listener is registered.

Now the listener itself looks like this:

```
namespace Vendor\MyExt\EventLister

use TYPO3\CMS\Core\Cache\Event\CacheFlushEvent;

use Psr\Log\LoggerInterface;

class CacheFlushEventListener
{
    
    private LoggerInterface $logger;

    public function __construct(LoggerInterface $logger) {
        $this->logger = $logger;
        $this->logger->error('test message 1');
    }

    public function __invoke(CacheFlushEvent $event): void
    {

        $this->logger->error('test message 2');
    }
}
```

To confirm that the listener is working, I've injected the `$logger` to simply output a message when the function gets called. But neither the message in the `constructor` nor in the `__invoke` method is logged.

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK you can't only inject the LoggerInterface.

Use the LoggerAwareInterface instead and the LoggerAwareTrait, to get all logs written correct and handled by TYPO3.

```php
namespace Vendor\MyExt\EventLister;

use TYPO3\CMS\Core\Cache\Event\CacheFlushEvent;
use Psr\Log\LoggerAwareInterface;
use Psr\Log\LoggerAwareTrait;

use Psr\Log\LoggerInterface;

class CacheFlushEventListener implements LoggerAwareInterface
{
    use LoggerAwareTrait;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->logger->error('test message 1');
    }

    public function __invoke(CacheFlushEvent $event): void
    {

        $this->logger->error('test message 2');
    }
}
```

Oh, and if the code above is posted correctly from your Code, the semicolon after namespace declaration is missing.